# std::stringstream operator>> fails to convert string to float

Tags: c++, stringstream

I can't understand why the second >> fails. Am I doing something wrong or missing some code?

```
std::ifstream file;
std::stringstream ss;
std::string str;
float f1, f2;

file.open("file.txt");
getline(file, str);
ss.str(str);
ss >> f1;

getline(file, str);//when packed inside if(), evalueates to true
ss.str(str);
ss >> f2; //when packed inside if(), evalueates to false - but why it fails?


std::cout<<"str = "<<str<<"\n";
std::cout<<"ss.str() = "<<ss.str()<<"\n";
std::cout<<"f1 = "<<f1<<"\nf2 = "<<f2<<"\n";
```

file:

```
0.120000
0.120000
```

output:

```
str = 0.120000
ss.str() = 0.120000
f1 = 0.12
f2 = 2.06831e+032
```

I have tried this code on multiple files and apparently only 1st insertion into float works, files have an empty line at the end

**Edit**

as Dan pointed, I tried extracting floats directly from file:

```
file.open("file.txt");
file >> f1;
file >> f2;
```

works ideally; also simplyfies code a lot

Comment: Ditch the `stringstream`, just use the stream `operator>>`s on the `ifstream` itself.

Comment: `file >> f1`. The file can do these things just as well as the stringstream.

Comment: Nice, that will simplify code a lot

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to add the following statement before the second attempt to read:

```
ss.clear();
```

**Why ?**

Because when you've read the first line, the string stream contains `"0.120000"` and `ss>>f1` will cause `ss` to reach the end of file. So that the eof flag is set.

When you reset the stringstreams's content with [`str()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/sstream/stringstream/str/), you don't reset the state flags, so that the attempt to read will fail. adding the ss.clear() after you've reset the stringstreams's content will correct this situation.

[Online demo](https://ideone.com/vCrNbb)

Comment: I added it before next getline; works now. I new I forgot something

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ sorry,  I came to the same conclusion and I was completing my answer while you made your comment ;-)