# C++ operator>> overloading issue: change object only once

Tags: c++, stream, operator-overloading, constructor-overloading

i have the following Vector3D code, and for some reason cin is able to change the object values only once. do you have any idea why? 
i guess it's something related to the 'const' definition but i'm not sure.
adding both code (partial) and test

```
// code:
class Vector3D
{
private:
    double _x, _y, _z;
public:
    Vector3D() : _x(0), _y(0), _z(0) {};
    Vector3D(double x, double y, double z) : _x(x), _y(y), _z(z) {};
    Vector3D(const double parm[DIMENSION]) : _x(parm[0]), _y(parm[1]), 
             _z(parm[2]) {};

    const Vector3D operator+(const Vector3D &other) const; 
    Vector3D &operator+=(const Vector3D &other);
    const double &operator[](int idx) const;
    double &operator[](int idx);
    friend ostream &operator<<(ostream &out, const Vector3D &c);
    friend istream &operator>>(istream &in, Vector3D &c);
};

const Vector3D Vector3D::operator+(const Vector3D &other) const {
    return Vector3D(*this) += other; 
}

Vector3D &Vector3D::operator+=(const Vector3D &other) {
    (*this)._x += other._x;
    (*this)._y += other._y;
    (*this)._z += other._z;
    return *this; 
}

const double &Vector3D::operator[](int idx) const {
    assert(idx >= 0 && idx < DIMENSION);
    switch (idx)
    {
        case 0:
            return _x;
        case 1:
            return _y;
        case 2:
            return _z;
        default:
            return _x; // not reachable
    }
}

double &Vector3D::operator[](int idx)
{
    assert(idx >= 0 && idx < DIMENSION);
    switch (idx)
    {
        case 0:
            return _x;
        case 1:
            return _y;
        case 2:
            return _z;
        default:
            return _x; // not reachable
    }
}

ostream &operator<<(ostream &out, const Vector3D &c)
{
    out << c._x << " " << c._y << " " << c._z;
    return out;
}

istream &operator>>(istream &in, Vector3D &c)
{
    in >> c._x >> c._y >> c._z;
    return in;
}



// test: 
void readFromStreamTest(int &tests) {
    std::stringstream os;
    os << 8.0 << " " << 3.0 << " " << 4.0;
    Vector3D a;
    os >> a;
    os << a; // "8 3 4"  as should be
    os.str(std::string());
    os << 2.1 << " " << 3.1 << " " << 4.1;
    os >> a;
    os.str(std::string());
    os << a;
    if (os.str()!=("2.1 3.1 4.1"))
    {
        std::cerr << "failed. should be 2.1 3.1 4.1 but was " << a;
    }
}
```

test results: "failed. should be 2.1 3.1 4.1 but was 8 3 4" (old values!!)

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please take some time to read [the help pages](https://stackoverflow.com/help) especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read about [how to ask good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Lastly please read this question [checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: This is a better question than most.. what are you suggesting is wrong @Ayxan? There is a clear test to show what is wrong and a description of what is expected, a complete listing of code (that at first glance looks like it should work).

Comment: @Rob Questions seeking debugging help are not the best type of questions, are they? The fact that there are worst questions doesn't change the fact that OP should have used their debugger first and reported the actual problem they are having rather than "Why doesn't work"

Comment: This is not an issue of the const, or you would have had a compile error. You should run this in a debugger and see if you are truly changing the content of the os stringstream.. or use a different instance of stringstream object for each assignment and read.

Comment: @Ayxan Its a new poster.. help him out :) He obviously put some effort in trying to put a lot of detail... maybe he needs help figuring out how to debug :) If we teach him how to, maybe he will help the next person :)

Comment: @Rob OP is a new contributor and that's why I kindly asked them to see the help pages. Besides, that code won't even compile, that's not a [mcve]

Comment: Your issue is related to [eof flag of stringstream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39052538/stdstringstream-operator-fails-to-convert-string-to-float)

Comment: thank you all!! as @tunglt propose, istream.clear() solve the issue! thank you all very much for the quick answer! 
as rob wrote, indeed i'm new here, and i will try to avoid asking debugging question. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use a *stringstream* like that, after extracting the contain throw `os >>` you cannot again modify it by `os.str(value)` nor `os <<` if you don't call `os.clear()` before, for instance

```
void readFromStreamTest(int &tests) {
  std::stringstream os;
  os << 8.0 << " " << 3.0 << " " << 4.0;
  Vector3D a;
  os >> a;
  os.clear();
  os << a; // "8 3 4"  as should be
  os.str(std::string());
  os << 2.1 << " " << 3.1 << " " << 4.1;
  os >> a;
  os.str(std::string());
  os.clear();
  os << a;
  if (os.str()!=("2.1 3.1 4.1"))
  {
    std::cerr << "failed. should be 2.1 3.1 4.1 but was " << a;
  }
}
```

P.S. I modified your original code to make it compilable

Comment: Hello @zoharhen, welcome to SO. If this answer your question, please accept or up vote it. That will give you both some reputation.